# TypeScript - 'new up' a class in a better way?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have a ton of models that I have always been structuring like so:

```
interface IPerson {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  fullName: string;
}

class Person implements IPerson {
  public firstName: string;
  public lastName: string;
  public fullName: string;
  constructor(_firstName: string, _lastName: string) {
    this.firstName = _firstName;
    this.lastName = _lastName;
    this.fullName = `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
  }
}
```

I then eventually call some api to return some json.

Example Response:

```
{
    "data": [
    {
      “firstName”: “John”,
      “lastName”: “Doe”
    },
    {
      “firstName”: “Jane”,
      “lastName”: “Doe”
    }
  ]
}
```

After I get the response, I would then just 'new it up' by doing something simple like:

`return response.data.map( d => new Person(d.firstName, d.lastName));`

My question:

I have some models that have quite a large set of properties and is seems extremely redundant to pass them in as parameters and bind them to the respective properties (at least that's what it feels like). Is there a more elegant way of doing this?

I see a lot of things that are similar to the below examples, but none of them seems to actually 'new up' the object in the class so it behaves correctly (ie: concatenating firstName and lastName).

Similar articles seems to mention something like this:

```
var modal: IModal = {
    content: '',
    form: '',
    href: '',
    $form: null,
    $message: null,
    $modal: null,
    $submits: null
};
```

other mention something along the lines of this:

```
modal: IModal = <IModal>{}
```

or

```
var modal = {} as IModal
```

Comment: The easiest (least amount of code which also leads to nice SoC IMO) is to map Json responses to interfaces (with no functionality). So do not use rich objects/types for these entities, leave that logic in the component or the html template.

Comment: This isn't really specific to typescript, but when deserializing it's typical to have a default constructor.  For your class would it be possible to move the logic of concatenation into the `fullName` property instead of in the constructor?

Comment: It would be possible, but if you can imagine, some of my other models require some other functions within the class to run in order to complete the object. For example, if the Person API return only a birthday, I would need to run a function to calculate age.

Comment: @mwilson - not sure why you can't do that in the component, a service, or in the template? You can do what you suggested, newing up for everything returned, but there is no magic LoC that will do it for you. So you either write the logic to do that and iterate over the returned object graph *or* you do as I suggested. Those are your 2 options....

Comment: @Igor: Yea, that's what I currently have setup. Everything is handeled within the service but was hoping there was a more elegant way to get something instantiated without all the code. I do see some really cool IDE extensions/plugins that allow you to paste in a JSON object and it creates the class/Interface for you. So that's cool i guess... (http://json2ts.com/) Visual Studio also has this (and some others (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rafaelsalguero.csharp2ts)

Comment: (https://jsfiddle.net/acj28ego/8/)

Comment: @Igor: Excuse the newb question, but can you define `SoC` and `LoC`. Do you have a link? I'm curious what those are...

Answer (score 3):

Write a constructor that takes an `IPerson`

```
interface IPerson {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  fullName: string;
}

class Person implements IPerson {
  public firstName: string;
  public lastName: string;
  public fullName: string;
  constructor(_firstName: string, _lastName: string) {
    this.firstName = _firstName;
    this.lastName = _lastName;
    this.fullName = `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
  }
  public static fromIPerson(person: IPerson): Person {
    return new Person(person.firstName, person.lastName);
  }
}
```

Comment: This may remove messy code from logical components but I don't think solves the problem, because you still have to list properties in `fromIPerson`.

Comment: @Hikmat G. I agree. However, I do like the concept of passing in the interface and letting the class new itself up and return that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Object.assign` in order not to list properties every time, but instead use data object itself. - [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-ym3h8z)

**UPDATE:**  declared a filter function to remove properties that not are not part of the class from source data. But there is drawback, that class properties have to have initial values in order them to appear in compiled javascript code. If they don't have initial values typescript class will be compiled empty, and there will no way of getting list of properties of typescript class in runtime.

```
function filter(obj, data) {
  return Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).reduce((acc, k) => {
    acc[k] = data[k];
    return acc;
  }, {})
}

class Person implements IPerson {
  public firstName: string = "";
  public lastName: string = "";
  public get fullName(): string {
    return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
  }
  constructor(data) {
    Object.assign(this, filter(this, data))
  }

}
```

Comment: I definitely use a similar method when there are too many properties to list them one by one in the constructor. Instead of doing `Object.assign` I am just doing a `for in loop`. `Object.assign` looks 1,000 times more elegant than a loop.

Comment: so this isn't why you posted the question I think. am I right? You don't even wanna do `new Person(data)` manually every time yes?

Comment: This is why I posted the question. The only thing I don't like about this solution is that if there are any 'extra' properties that are found within data (which there usually are) then they get thrown into that model even though they aren't supposed to be there. But, generally speaking, this is the most attractive solution thus far. Example: `const p = new Person({firstName: 'frank', lastName:'smith', someOtherProperty: 42});` // someOtherProperty will be a part of the object.

Comment: Not a bad compromise. But, this would essentially mean that I would need to create a utils file so I can import that function into all my classes for usage.

Comment: Nothing, really. It just kind of goes along with the other suggestions (some type of extra step to handle the `new Class(...)` part. I was hoping that there was some 'out of the box' typescript feature I hadn't run across yet.